# Converting escaped html back into HTML string in flash

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

Using swfobject I'm passing a xml string containg html which i escape using php htmlentites.

How would one go about converting it back to a valid xml string in flash as2?

```
flashvars.xmlString = "&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?&gt;&lt;names&gt;&lt;name&gt;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I stumbled across it and thought I had a better answer for AS3 (since the question is tagged with the language).

In AS3 you can do it pretty easily. Here's escape:

```
return XML(new XMLNode(XMLNodeType.TEXT_NODE, string)).toXMLString();
```

And here's unescape:

```
return new XMLDocument(string).firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly AS2 doesn't naturally support encoding/decoding entities. If you could instead URL encode the XML then you could use AS2s built in escape and unescape functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest in Actionscript 3.0:

```
str.replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
```

The easiest way to achieve that in Actionscript 2.0 is by using a TextField.
set the textField.htmlText property with your escaped string and get it un-escaped from the textField.text property.

Will work for 3.0 as well but it's much slower

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.htmlText = "&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?&gt;&lt;names&gt;&lt;name&gt;";
trace(tf.text);
```

After some bench-marking I won't recommend the TextField for long string.